# How to migrate from a MySQL master-master setup to a master-master setup with as little as possible downtime

Tags: mysql, replication, migration, mysql-8.0

I have to conduct a migration of a few databases from two MySQL VMs with master-master replication to another 2 VMS that would be also master-master replication. How would you do it with minimal downtime and no additional troubles?

Any tips, advices are appreciated

Comment: If this will be a task that you will do many times, look at LVM.